# Controlling Clang Warnings

Tags: llvm, clang

I've compiled the SQLite amalgamation source into my iOS project, and `clang` throws a warning on this line

```
mask = (sizeof(long)==8) ? LARGEST_INT64 : 0x7fffffff;
```

with the following warning:

```
Implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'long' changes value from
9223372036854775807 to -1
[warn_impcast_integer_precision_constant]
```

I've enabled `-fdiagnostics-show-name` to show the name (`warn_impcast_integer_precision_constant`).

I certainly don't want to change anything in the SQLite source, since I don't want to introduce unforseen side effects, so I'd like to disable this specific warning just for that one line. The warning is certainly valid, but cannot occur anyway with the `sizeof` check in place.

To make this process reproducible for other warnings and diagnostics, is there a method to find out the specific warning class and disable them for one line? Unfortunately I can't find anything in the so called `clang/llvm` "documentation".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any remotely recent version of clang should be printing the flag associated with a given warning along with the warning (in this case -Wconstant-conversion); not sure why you are not seeing this.  And to turn it off, you can use `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wconstant-conversion"`.

Comment: Where do you see `constant-conversion`? Xcode doesn't show me anything other than the warning text.

Comment: Oh... Xcode does a bunch of manipulation of clang's output; I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: In Xcode you can `View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator` to see the actual build output. Select the warning or error your want more information about, and click the "lines" icon on right of the line to see the output (including something like `warning: something something [-Wreason-why]`

Comment: Also note that, if you want to re-enable this check (and you should) you can wrap it with `#pragma clang diagnostic push` and `#pragma clang diagnostic pop`

Answer (score 1):

as quoted from the user manual lined by sir Chris Lattner:

In the below example -Wmultichar is ignored for only a single line of code, after which the diagnostics return to whatever state had previously existed.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"
char b = 'df'; // no warning.
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But more importantly, would it not be more prudent to consider the type of variable that 'mask' is, and what 'mask' represents?

Since you're doing something depending on whether the size of long is 8, should it perhaps be of type uint64_t?

What if sizeof(long) is actually 16 instead of 8 or 4 (which I guess you expect it to be when it is not 8)? Is 0x7fffffff then still the mask you need? Or perhaps you really want to assign it LONG_MAX from limits.h rather then the current construction.

Comment: OP explicitly said that he didn’t want to change the SQLite source at all.

Answer (score -1):

The clang user manual is here:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html

It discusses various topics related to diagnostics.  There are other useful documents in the sidebar of http://clang.llvm.org/